# Plotting graphs in C++

Tags: python, c++, graph

I have made the following graph using matplotlib in python.I have also attached the code I used to make this.[image]

The code for the arena

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

obs_boundary = [
            [0, 0, 10, 600],
            [0, 600, 900, 10],
            [10, 0, 900, 10],
            [900, 10, 10, 600]
        ]
obs_cir_own = [
    [50,500,10],
    [100,300,10],
    [240,240,10],
    [300,400,10],
    [190,50,10]

        ]
obs_cir_opp = [
            [700, 420, 10],
            [460, 200, 10],
            [550, 500, 10],
            [670, 70, 10],
            [800, 230, 10],
            [600,300,10]
        ]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for (ox, oy, w, h) in obs_boundary:
    print(ox, oy, w, h)        
    ax.add_patch(
                patches.Rectangle(
                    (ox, oy), w, h,
                    edgecolor='black',
                    facecolor='black',
                    fill=True
                )
            )

for (ox, oy,r) in obs_cir_own:
            ax.add_patch(
                patches.Circle(
                    (ox, oy), r,
                    edgecolor='black',
                    facecolor='green',
                    fill=True
                )
            )
for (ox, oy, r) in obs_cir_opp:
            ax.add_patch(
                patches.Circle(
                    (ox, oy), r,
                    edgecolor='black',
                    facecolor='red',
                    fill=True
                )
            )
 
plt.plot(50,50, "bs", linewidth=30)
plt.plot(870, 550, "ys", linewidth=30)           
name='arena'
plt.title(name)
plt.axis("equal")
```

So, I want to implement a similar arena using C++ and I have no idea how to do it? I researched I got to know something about qtplot again I dont know much about qt. So, is qtplot the only way or there are some easier way. Please tell me how to implement this in C++.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are re-implementing this in C++?

Comment: Just have your c++ dump the data somewhere and then have it invoke the python script.

Comment: @UnholySheep i have a path planning algorithm to test which is in C++ so i need a graph in C++ as above

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp, which looks like it is just a wrapper around matplotlib anyway, so you are still calling/using Python and matplotlib in the end. With this you probably can copy your code nearly verbatim to "C++".

Comment: actually i will use it to test a path planning algorithm which is in c++, so can i use this to my purpose? means can i call it from a c++ code?

Answer (score 6):

An excellent C++ library to plot graphs is **ROOT**. It was developed by CERN for physicists. It also includes a C++ shell, in case you want to use C++ with an interactive prompt.

You can find the documentation, download links, and lots of examples, at https://root.cern/.

There is also a stackoverflow question by someone trying to plot points: [CERN ROOT: Is is possible to plot pairs of x-y data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654406/cern-root-is-is-possible-to-plot-pairs-of-x-y-data-points)

Answer (score 0):

Make graphs is C++ is not as easy as in python. So if you can keep using your python code. Otherwise you can use OpenGL. Here there is the tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/. And I think this is what you need: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Scientific_OpenGL_Tutorial_02

Comment: While I'm happy you mention the Scientific OpenGL Tutorial which I wrote, I think it's not the way to go if you just want a simple library to plot graphs :)

Comment: @G.Sliepen so can you suggest a easier way to plot graphs?

Comment: What about plotutils then? http://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/ . It is an official C++ library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs

Comment: @SHIVANSHUSAHOO I'm afraid I don't have a good answer myself. It looks like matplotlib-cpp is a good option for you, as mentioned by Jan Crhistoph Terasa.