# Plotting inside a picture or video

Tags: python, c++, plot, graph, video-processing

I have a system written in C++ that do some processing on some input video. As a result of this processing I get some statistics .
Right now the system produces number data that is saved on a text file.
Later I have written some python script that takes these numbers and shows some plots.

I was thinking, it would be nice if I can put this info *in* the video.

If it is just numerical values I can do that easily with the text writing functions in OpenCV.

However, perhaps it would be nice to include a small plot *in the video*.

How can I do that? Does OpenCV has something of this sort?

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667255/plotting-graphs-in-c) about plotting with C++. I wonder if some answers there could be of any help. (As you can see the nature of the question although related is a bit different)

I am thinking I can go in one of two ways:

1. Implementing this plotting and then embedding the plot directly in my C++ code immediately after finding the values

or

2. Processing the video, getting the values in a text file as now, and then processing this text file, the video in Python to embed a plot in it

The key concept here is embedding a small plot in a video. How can I do that in either C++ or python?

Comment: Did you mean overlay picture in the video using opencv?

Comment: yes exactly     that is what i mean